# What are createBackgroundSubtractorKNN parameters in OpenCV C++?

Tags: c++, opencv, knn

I need explanations on parameters of

```
createBackgroundSubtractorKNN(int history=500, double dist2Threshold=400.0, bool detectShadows=true)
```

How do history, dist2Threshold, and detectShadows affect the background substractor ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sometimes, the easiest way to understand function's parameters is by playing with them. Here is what I could figure out by reading the [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/de/de1/group__video__motion.html#gac9be925771f805b6fdb614ec2292006d) and testing out the function :

- **history** is the number of *frames used to build the statistic model* of the background. The smaller the value is, the faster changes in the background will be taken into account by the model and thus be considered as background. And vice versa.
- **dist2Threshold** is a *threshold* to define whether a *pixel is different* from the background or not. The smaller the value is, the more sensitive movement detection is. And vice versa.
- **detectShadows** : If set to true, shadows will be displayed in *gray* on the *generated mask*. (Example bellow)

[image: Gray color region shows shadow region]

Hope my explanations make sens and that it's a bit clearer for you now.